# latex notation not working on pycharm 2016.3

Tags: python, latex, ipython, pycharm, jupyter

I'm following the official tutorial, [Using IPython/Jupyter Notebook with PyCharm > Writing formulae](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/2016.3/using-ipython-jupyter-notebook-with-pycharm.html#d469869e306).

When I write `$$c = \sqrt{a^2 + b^2}$$` as markdown and execute it, it does not show formula correctly but it shows like this.

[image: latex notion show like this on pycharm]

I'm expecting to be shown like this (cite from https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/2016.3/using-ipython-jupyter-notebook-with-pycharm.html#d469869e306), and it can be shown nicely in browser but not in PyCharm.

> [image]

Does anyone know how to fix it?

My environment:

- Windows 10
- PyCharm 2016.3
- python 3.5 (anaconda)

Comment: I noticed that when I add "new empty line" before the `$$c = \sqrt{a^2 + b^2}$$` statement, it works well. Might it be a bug in PyCharm?

Comment: I reproduce the problem with this and other LaTeX expressions in PyCharm 2016.3 under OS X, also python 3.5. I see them right by the Jupyter web server so it seems a PyCharm issue.

Answer (score 1):

It seems a bug related with this issue: [Jupyter Notebook fails to properly handle IPython.display Math](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-21450?query=display%20markdown#tab=Comments). The bug will be solved in 2017.1 release (stable release still not available [March 4th, 2017]) but you can get the [PyCharm Early Access Program](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/nextversion/?fromIDE=) version that has the problem solved:

- [Download PyCharm EAP for mac](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/download/download-thanks.html?type=eap&platform=mac)
- [Download PyCharm EAP for Windows](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/download/download-thanks.html?type=eap&platform=win)

I tested the mac EAP release and it solves the issue that you are reporting.